# What should I do to upload the file using jsp/servlet and storing in the ms-access db

Tags: file-upload

this is my productregistration.jsp I want to upload the image and want to also send the data to servlet which is ProductRegistartionServlet.java....can you help me? how it can be possible...
I have already added both jar files named as common-io and common-file-upload

```
 <form action="/eauction/ProductRegistrationServlet" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" method="post">
           <div class="form_row">
            <label class="contact"><strong>Product Image:</strong></label>
           <input type="file" class="contact_input" required="required" name="file" />
         </div>
             <div class="form_row">
            <label class="contact"><strong>Product Name:</strong></label>
           <input type="text" class="contact_input" required="required" name="p_name" />
         </div>
         <div class="form_row">
           <label class="contact"><strong>Product Type:</strong></label>
           <input type="text" class="contact_input" name="p_type" />
         </div>
         <div class="form_row">
           <label class="contact"><strong>Product Prize:</strong></label>
           <input type="text" class="contact_input" name="p_prize" required="required" />
         </div>
         <div class="form_row">
           <label class="contact"><strong>Product:</strong></label>
           <input type="text" class="contact_input" min="8" max="10" name="p_product" required="required" />
         </div>
         <div class="form_row">
           <label class="contact"><strong>Product Details:</strong></label>
           <textarea name="p_detail" class="contact_input" size="200"></textarea>
         </div>

         <p>&nbsp;</p>
         <p>&nbsp;</p>
         <div class="form_row">
             <input type="image" src="images/GoDf5.gif" alt="submit form"/>
         </div>
</form>
```

here is my servlet help me to figure out the problem please
and this is my ProductRegistrationServlet.java

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;

/**
 *
 * @author Samkit
 */
public class ProductRegistrationServlet extends HttpServlet {


    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {

    }


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        List<FileItem> items = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);
        for (FileItem item : items) {
            if (item.isFormField()) {
                // Process regular form field (input type="text|radio|checkbox|etc", select, etc).
                String fieldname = item.getFieldName();
                String fieldvalue = item.getString();
                // ... (do your job here)
                String p_name =request.getParameter("p_name");
                String p_type=request.getParameter("p_type");
                String p_prize=request.getParameter("p_prize");
                String p_product=request.getParameter("p_product");
                String p_detail=request.getParameter("p_detail");
                System.out.print(p_name);

            } else {
                // Process form file field (input type="file").
                String fieldname = item.getFieldName();
                String filename = FilenameUtils.getName(item.getName());
                DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(item.getInputStream());
                // ... (do your job here)
                String contentType = request.getContentType();
        String saveFile="";
                int formDataLength = request.getContentLength();
            byte dataBytes[] = new byte[formDataLength];
            int byteRead = 0;
            int totalBytesRead = 0;
            while(totalBytesRead < formDataLength){
            byteRead = in.read(dataBytes, totalBytesRead,formDataLength);
            totalBytesRead += byteRead;
            }
            String file = new String(dataBytes);
            saveFile = file.substring(file.indexOf("filename=\"") + 10);
            saveFile = saveFile.substring(0, saveFile.indexOf("\n"));
            saveFile = saveFile.substring(saveFile.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1,saveFile.indexOf("\""));
            int lastIndex = contentType.lastIndexOf("=");
            String boundary = contentType.substring(lastIndex + 1,contentType.length());
            int pos;
            pos = file.indexOf("filename=\"");
            pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
            pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
            pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
            int boundaryLocation = file.indexOf(boundary, pos) - 4;
            int startPos = ((file.substring(0, pos)).getBytes()).length;
            int endPos = ((file.substring(0, boundaryLocation)).getBytes()).length;
            File ff = new File("C:/"+saveFile);
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(ff);
            fileOut.write(dataBytes, startPos, (endPos - startPos));
            fileOut.flush();
            fileOut.close();
            }
        }
    } catch (FileUploadException e) {
        throw new ServletException("Cannot parse multipart request.", e);
    }

    // ...
}}



/*

        Connection con = null;
        ResultSet rst = null;
        Statement st = null;


        try{

                Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:register");
                st =con.createStatement();
               rst = st.executeQuery("Select * from productregisteration");
               int i = st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO productregisteration VALUES('"+ff.getPath()+"','"+p_name+"','"+p_type+"','"+p_prize+"','"+p_product+"','"+p_detail+"')");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(WelcomeServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }            catch(SQLException se){
        }
     }
    }}*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;

public class ProductRegistrationServlet extends HttpServlet {

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  try {   
    File savedFile = null;
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String   p_name="",p_type="",p_detail="",p_prize="",p_product="",itemName="",User_Name="";
    List<FileItem> items = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);
    for (FileItem item : items) {
      if (item.isFormField()) {
        // Process regular form field (input type="text|radio|checkbox|etc", select, etc).

        String fieldname = item.getFieldName();
        String fieldvalue = item.getString();
       // ... (do your job here)
         if(fieldname.equals("p_type")){
           p_type = fieldvalue;
         }
         if(fieldname.equals("p_name")){
           p_name = fieldvalue;
           out.println(p_name);
         }
         if(fieldname.equals("p_prize")){
           p_prize = fieldvalue;
         }
         if(fieldname.equals("p_product")){
           p_product = fieldvalue;
         }
         if(fieldname.equals("p_detail")){
           p_detail = fieldvalue;
         }
      }
      else {
        itemName = item.getName();
        savedFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Samkit\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\eauction\\web\\upload\\"+itemName);
        out.println(savedFile);
        item.write(savedFile);
      }
    }
    Connection con = null;
        ResultSet rst = null;
        Statement st = null;
        try{
                Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:register");
                st=con.createStatement();






                  //Getting the date only
                   DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                   Date date = new Date();
                   String p_date = dateFormat.format(date);
                    System.out.println(p_date);
                   //Getting the time only
                  Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
                  String am_pm;
                  int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
                  int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                  int second = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                  if(calendar.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == 0)
                  am_pm = "AM";
```

Comment: i am storing only imagename in to my database name and getting it from the upload folder